# HTML select tag can not be used on cell in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

If you use the HTML select tag on the cell, it can not select the value. Perhaps I think that the click event is deprived of something.

I changed the options below and tried, the result did not change.

- readOnly (true)
- editor (false)
- disableVisualSelection (true)
- fillHandle (false)
- filter (false)

Is there a solution?

Firefox and IE will not work, Chrome will work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dJNu.png)

Comment: please post the code you have tried till now

Comment: post the code, not cleared with your problem